# My winning image displays after the screen resets in Hangman Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a switch statement that will display the winning image based on the song. The functionality works it just displays the image after the screen is reset for the next word. I would like it to display when you get the word correct and before screen resets.

I have tried putting it in different order in the code, in the same setTimeout() function as the alert, and also throwing it in its own setTimeout(). I can't turn anything else up on researching this issue.

```js
//Global Variables===========================================================
// Used to check if the letters were already used
let lettersAlpha;
let songArr = ["caliente"];
// let songArr = ["caliente", "imposible", "bloqueo", "amanece", "desconocidos"];
let wins = 0;
let losses = 0;
let blanksAndSuccesses = [];
let userGuess;
let guessesLeft = 12;
let lettersUsed = [];
let randSong;

//Reset========================================================================
const reset = () => {
  lettersAlpha = ['a', 'b', 'c',
    'd', 'e', 'f',
    'g', 'h', 'i',
    'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o',
    'p', 'q', 'r',
    's', 't', 'u',
    'v', 'w', 'x',
    'y', 'z'
  ];

  //Erase word from last game
  blanksAndSuccesses.splice(0);
  //Clear the letters used last game
  lettersUsed.splice(0);
  //Get random song
  randSong = songArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * songArr.length)];
  console.log(randSong);

  //Create underscores based on number of letters
  for (let i = 0; i < randSong.length; i++) {
    blanksAndSuccesses.push("_");
  }
  //Reset Game Area
  $("#wordToGuess").html(blanksAndSuccesses.join(" "));
  //Reset Letters Guessed
  guessesLeft = 12;
  $("#numGuesses").html(`Guesses Left: ${guessesLeft}`);
  $("#lettersGuessed").html("Letters Guessed: ");
};

//Check guess right/wrong
let guessChecker = userGuess => {
  //True means letter is NOT used
  if (
    lettersAlpha.indexOf(userGuess) != -1 &&
    randSong.indexOf(userGuess) != -1
  ) {
    //Check against word
    for (let i = 0; i < randSong.length; i++) {
      if (userGuess === randSong[i]) {
        blanksAndSuccesses[i] = userGuess;
      }
    }
    //Remove the letter from the unused letters array
    lettersAlpha.splice(lettersAlpha.indexOf(userGuess), 1);
    //Update board
    $("#wordToGuess").html(blanksAndSuccesses.join(" ").toUpperCase());
    //Update guesses left (numGuesses)
    guessesLeft--;
    $("#numGuesses").html(`Guesses Left: ${guessesLeft}`);
    //Update letters guessed
    lettersUsed.push(userGuess);
    $("#lettersGuessed").html(
      "Letters Guessed: " + lettersUsed.join(",").toUpperCase()
    );
  } else if (
    lettersAlpha.indexOf(userGuess) != -1 &&
    randSong.indexOf(userGuess) == -1
  ) {
    //Remove from usable letters
    lettersAlpha.splice(lettersAlpha.indexOf(userGuess), 1);
    //Update numGuesses
    guessesLeft--;
    $("#numGuesses").html(`Guesses Left: ${guessesLeft}`);
    //Update letters guessed
    lettersUsed.push(userGuess);
    $("#lettersGuessed").html(
      "Letters Guessed: " + lettersUsed.join(",").toUpperCase()
    );
  }
};

//Display Album Art
let winImage = function(song) {
  switch (song) {
    case "caliente":
      console.log("Here");
      $("#albumIMG").html('<img src="assets/images/caliente_album_art.jpg" />');
      break;

    case "imposible":
      $("#albumIMG").prepend(
        '<img src="assets/images/imposible_album_art.png" />'
      );
      break;

    case "bloqueo":
      $("#albumIMG").prepend(
        '<img src="assets/images/bloqueo_album_art.jpg" />'
      );
      break;

    case "desconocido":
      $("#albumIMG").prepend(
        '<img src="assets/images/desconocidos_album_art.jpg" />'
      );
      break;

    case "#amanence":
      $("albumIMG").prepend(
        '<img src="assets/images/amenece_album_art.jpg" />'
      );
  }
};

//Check win condition
let winCondtion = function() {
  if (blanksAndSuccesses.join("") === randSong) {
    //Update wins
    wins++;
    $("#numWins").html(`Wins: ${wins}`);
    setTimeout(function() {
      winImage(randSong)
    }, 1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(`Congrats! You've won. The song was ${randSong.toUpperCase()}.`);
      reset();
    }, 0);
    // alert(`Congrats! You've won. The song was ${randSong.toUpperCase()}.`)
  } else if (guessesLeft == 0) {
    //Update losses
    losses++;
    $("#numLosses").html(`Losses: ${losses}`);
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(`Sorry! You've lost. The song was ${randSong.toUpperCase()}.`);
      reset();
    }, 0);
    // alert(`Congrats! You've won. The song was ${randSong.toUpperCase()}.`)
    //Reset game board
  }
};

//Keypress function/Play Game
$(document).keyup(e => {
  userGuess = e.key;
  guessChecker(userGuess);
  winCondtion();
});

reset();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wordToGuess"></div>
<div id="numGuesses"></div>
<div id="lettersGuessed"></div>
<div id="albumIMG"></div>
```

Comment: You call reset() with a 0ms delay and winImage() with a 1ms delay. Sequentially, your app is doing what you asked it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your first if block inside of winCondtion, remove your `winImage(randsong)` amd alert from the setTimeout callback and place your `reset()` function inside of the setTimeout callback.  This will allow for your image to appear - reset will be run after the delay, in this example it will be 1000ms.

```
let winCondtion = function() {
if (blanksAndSuccesses.join("") === randSong) {
    //Update wins
    wins++;
    $("#numWins").html(`Wins: ${wins}`);
    alert(`Congrats! You've won. The song was ${randSong.toUpperCase()}.`);
    winImage(randSong)
    setTimeout(() => {
        reset();
    }, 1000);
} else if (guessesLeft == 0) {
    //Update losses
    losses++;
    $("#numLosses").html(`Losses: ${losses}`);
    alert(`Sorry! You've lost. The song was ${randSong.toUpperCase()}.`);
  }
};
```

More on setTimeout: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: I was reading the documentation for it before posting this but thank you so much for your help. This must seem so basic but I spent a long time on it. I really appreciate it. Have a great rest of the week.